# Can white-space: pre-line be set of a specific height in CSS?

Tags: css

Is there a way to set the space of white-space pre-line?

I don't want line height which also affects the text of the paragraph, only of the pre-line line breaks height.

Thank you

Comment: can you create an example in stack snippet..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pre-line will ignore extra spaces but it won't ignore extra lines. Since pre-line is a value of white-space, you can't set the value of a value. So only way to make space in between lines with pre-line is to just to skip lines in your actual code like so:

```
<p>example

example
example


example</p>
```